# Does a "typical" reproducing kernel on a manifold generate an infinite-dimensional RKHS?

Tags: functional-analysis, manifolds, differential-topology, hilbert-spaces

Let $M$ be a finite dimensional manifold and $k:M\times M\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ a smooth reproducing kernel. Is the set of all such $k$ with the property that the reproducing kernel Hilbert space generated by $k$ is infinite dimensional an open subset of the collection of all smooth reproducing kernels?

More generally, are there any references that investigate how the set of reproducing kernels on a manifold is organized according to RKHS dimension?

Comment: I believe that finite dimensional spaces are dense when we only consider continuous RKHS,as we can triangulate the manifold and approximate any other RK by its values on the vertices and extending  with convex combinations on all the simplices. But I don't know if it will still be positive definite..

Comment: @BrianRushton I think I'm having trouble understanding your approximation scheme. Putting aside positive definiteness for now, how does it produce a symmetric function on $M\times M$?

Comment: By taking a symmetric triangulation of $M \times M$. It was just an idea that probably doesn't work; that's why I made it a comment and not an answer.